# Error when trying "profile search form" from frontend

Tags: profile, joomla, search, 4.7

I've recently moved to a different hosting and had to change configuration. The site runs on Joomla 3.5.1 with CiviCrm 4.7.4 which was upgraded to 4.7.7
Everything seems to be running fine except for the profile search option from the frontend. 
The search age is displayed correctly, but when I select one of the search parameters and hit SEARCH a get the following error:

The requested page can't be found.

Then some unformatted code:
  @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. One of parameters (value: `Home-country`) is not of the type MysqlColumnName

[Return to home page.](http://www.sietareu.org/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

The site worked normally on Civicrm 4.7.4 (I've also had a look at a local copy and it runs fine with 4.7.4) but it's a reall hassle with 4.7.7
Has anyone seen a simiular error? Any ideas as to the possible cause?

Civicrm runs very well on the backend, the issue is only with the frontend. No parameters have been changes. The only change done was to upgrade to the newest version of Civicrm.

Comment: Have you checked on the joomla test site? (assuming it is up to date)